# Getting Page Headers with Crystal Reports Subreports

Tags: crystal-reports

Perhaps you can help me with a problem I am having with Crystal Reports. I have a sub-report that has its own set a page headers. These are distinct from the page headers of the main report.

The heading show up when I run the sub-report by itself but when I run the main report, the heading portion of the sub-report is suppressed, only the detail lines show.

I cannot solve this by moving the heading to the main report because the sub-report is used in all three of my reports. In two of the reports I have two distinct detail sections.

I also tried to create group headers for the sub-reports. These are also suppressed in the main report.

Any help will be appreciated, I have been struggling with this problem for several day.

Answer (score 0):

You can create additional page header sections and suppress them conditionally

Answer (score 0):

Open the section expert within Crystal Reports whilst looking at the subreport

select the report header section

check that the "common" options does not have a tick next to hide, suppress

save the report and test